# HTC Desire dialer misinterprets fragment in URI and runs USSD code. Is there anyway around that?

Tags: ussd, android

Code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber + "#fragment");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

When the above code is executed, the htc desire dialer starts executing a USSD command.
This does not occur on nexus one or Galaxy S and many other phones i'm testing on.

It seems the dialer is misinterpreting the # sign and executing the USSD command even though there's no * at the beginning of the number.

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution, because I have the problem even on two different Galagy Gio's. One is working fine, the other starts the USSD running and tells me unknown application

Comment: Is there a * anywhere in the phone number?